# how to change the path of source file in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I'm new to power bi. I have developed a dashboard on power bi desktop. It reads some .csv files as data source. Now I need to move it to another machine, names of those csv files are the same, path is the only thing to be updated.
Is it possible to change the path only, instead of rebuilding this dashboard? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Power BI Desktop:

1. Go to File - Options - Data Source settings
2. Select your csv-file
3. Click the **Change Source ...** button and change the file path

Comment: thank you. Is there a refresh button after updating source file on power bi desktop? So far, I can only refresh the data after uploading to power bi pro.

Comment: There is a refresh button on the Home tab next to the Transform data (PowerQuery) button.